# Custom Vectorization in numpy for string arrays

Tags: pandas, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I am trying to apply `vectorization with custom function` on `numpy string arrays`.

Example:

```
import numpy

test_array = numpy.char.array(["sample1-sample","sample2-sample"])

numpy.char.array(test_array.split('-'))[:,0]
```

Op:

```
chararray([b'sample1', b'sample2'], dtype='|S7')
```

But these are `in-built` functions, is there any other method to achieve `vectorization with custom functions`. Example, with the following function:

```
def custom(text):
    return text[0]
```

Comment: You can vectorize any function with np.vectorize https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html . However its mostly syntactic sugar and its implementation is a for loop according to numpy themselves. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but using built-in fonctions is generally goood practice.

Comment: Even the `np.char` functions use python string methods, and aren't faster than a list comprehension with same method.  Fast 'vectorization' as done with numeric dtypes isn't possible with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` doesn't implement fast string methods (as it does for numeric dtypes).  So the `np.char` code is more for convenience than performance.

```
In [124]: alist=["sample1-sample","sample2-sample"]
In [125]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [126]: carr = np.char.array(alist)
```

A straightforward list comprehension versus your code:

```
In [127]: [item.split('-')[0] for item in alist]
Out[127]: ['sample1', 'sample2']
In [128]: np.char.array(carr.split('-'))[:,0]
Out[128]: chararray([b'sample1', b'sample2'], dtype='|S7')
In [129]: timeit [item.split('-')[0] for item in alist]
664 ns ± 32.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In [130]: timeit np.char.array(carr.split('-'))[:,0]
20.5 µs ± 297 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

For the simple task of clipping the strings, there is a fast `numpy` way - using a shorter `dtype`:

```
In [131]: [item[0] for item in alist]
Out[131]: ['s', 's']
In [132]: carr.astype('S1')
Out[132]: chararray([b's', b's'], dtype='|S1')
```

But assuming that's just an example, not your real world custom action, I suggest using lists.

`np.char` recommends using the `np.char` functions and ordinary array instead of `np.char.array`.  The functionality is basically the same.  But using the `arr` above:

```
In [140]: timeit np.array(np.char.split(arr, '-').tolist())[:,0]
13.8 µs ± 90.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`np.char` functions often produce string dtype arrays, but split creates an object dtype array of lists:

```
In [141]: np.char.split(arr, '-')
Out[141]: 
array([list(['sample1', 'sample']), list(['sample2', 'sample'])],
      dtype=object)
```

Object dtype arrays are essentially lists.

```
In [145]: timeit [item[0] for item in np.char.split(arr, '-').tolist()]
9.08 µs ± 27.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Your code is relatively slow because it takes time to convert this array of lists into a new `chararray`.